# How to find and replace all the words in a cell with a new word in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007, export-to-excel

I have a huge data set in excel. I have a column with list of certain information about fruits and Im trying to replace all the cells with BA and BSC in column A with a new word fruits as given below in column B in excel. any new suggestions will be appreciated.

```
example

A                                           B
KFC34R BA red and yellow                fruits
KFC34R BSC red and yellow               fruits
KFC34R BA red and yellow                fruits
```

Comment: And you've tried?

Comment: Is the current answer getting what you want or is something missing?

Answer (score 1):

Try `=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1, "BA", B1), "BSC", B1))`